# Cannot make slick 3.2 Mapped table example working

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I'm just trying to make "User" example working (http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/schemas.html#mapped-tables), but it doesn't compile.

As I'm targeting MySQL, I added th folowing imports :

```
import slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.Table
import slick.jdbc._
import slick.lifted._
```

That didn't compiled either, I got a lot of errors like

```
Error:(16, 23) could not find implicit value for parameter tt: slick.ast.TypedType[Int]
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
```

After looking for implicits, I added `with MySQLProfile.ImplicitColumnTypes` to the `Users` class extending `Table`:

```
class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") with MySQLProfile.ImplicitColumnTypes
```

Now I'm stuck with

```
Error:(19, 15) value ? is not a member of slick.lifted.Rep[Int]
  def * = (id.?, first, last) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply _)
```

`<>` is not found either.

You may notice `User.unapply _` instead of `User.unapply` as stated in doc; but the compiler was complaining whith `User.unapply`

What I'm I doing wrong ? Why is the doc so unclear ?

Comment: Please note that this example from slick 3.2.0 doc is working flawlessly without code modifications with slick 3.1.1 and 2 simple import (`slick.lifted._` and `slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code imports `slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.Table` but instead it needs to bring in the whole api:

```
import slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api._
```

That will give you the implicts you were looking for, and the code should compile.

---

#### BTW: the Slick examples are compiled

Incidently, the Slick manual examples are compiled. This means you can get to the code to see if there are extra details in there you need.

For example, for the page you linked to, if you scroll to the top there's an "Edit this page on github" link. Clicking that takes you to [the source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/slick/slick/b4bce6bb0f347211650355e9ab42a1616b94007e/slick/src/sphinx/schemas.rst) and in there you'll find a reference to the Scala source:

```
.. includecode:: code/LiftedEmbedding.scala#mappedtable
```

...and that file is also in GitHub: [LiftedEmbedding.scala](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/slick/slick/b4bce6bb0f347211650355e9ab42a1616b94007e/slick/src/sphinx/code/LiftedEmbedding.scala)

A bit long-winded, but useful sometimes to know the examples are compiled and you can find them.

The details of how that happens are just about to change to a different system, but the principles should remain the same. The details (filenames, import syntax) above will be different.

Comment: Thx. Sure, this is not very visible in the doc. Know sbt compile fine, IdeaCE is bugging on <> ;) But that's another story...

Comment: I get the same problem with import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._ Error is: value <> is not a member of (slick.lifted.Rep[Long], slick.lifted.Rep[Option[String]] ....